# Replace values to either always increase or be the same as value before it

Tags: r, data.table

My specific desire is hard to describe without an example, so here it goes.  The raw data I have looks like this:

```
Data <- data.table(ID = c("Car1", "Car2", "Car3", "Car4", "Car5", "Car6"),
                   Consumer_Teir = c(1,2,1,2,3,3))
```

I want to replace the `Consumer_Teir` values so they are always increasing or the same as the value before it.  So in this example, the 1 that is surrounded by 2s should become a 2.

Desired output:

```
Data <- data.table(ID = c("Car1", "Car2", "Car3", "Car4", "Car5", "Car6"),
                   Consumer_Teir = c(1,2,2,2,3,3))
```

My actual data may have a 2 with a large back of 1s after it, so a straight x1>x2 | x1==x2 may not actually work without a repeating loop, which is very time intensive.  I'm sure there is a type of fill that does this, but I don't know what this fill is to be able to find it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

We could use `cummax`

```
Data[, Consumer_Teir := cummax(Consumer_Teir)]
```